# How to turn off always showing current directory in cmder

Tags: cmder

It creates unnecessary bloat, pwd would suffice for me. Couldn't find anything in settings.

[image: highlighted in green]

Comment: listen, I appreciate the help, I really do but could you please explain it to me like I'm 5? I'm not a power linux shell user, I just use cmder on Windows to run my Python scripts.
All it sounds to me like gibberish or a magic spell. I would really appreciate dumbed down instructions to make that 'path' not distract me.

Something like: 'open this file, put this in there, done.'

Comment: Edit `init.bat` and remove everything after `@prompt`

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I turn off always showing current directory in cmder?

In the latest version 1.3.11.843 you can:

- Close cmder
- Edit `vendor\clink.lua`
- Go to line 50
- Replace `cmder_prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg}{svn} \n\x1b[1;39;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"` with `cmder_prompt = "{lamb} "`
- Save `vendor\clink.lua`
- Run cmder

Note:

- There is probably a more elegant way to achieve this, as there is a warning at the top of the file "Use `"%CMDER_ROOT%\config\<whatever>.lua"` to add your lua startup scripts" but I haven't figured out how to add a copy to the startup scripts and have it execute correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.3.19, go to `vendor` folder, open `clink.lua` file and comment this line

> `prompt = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)`

You comment with --

> `-- prompt = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)`

And remove **`{cwd}`** from this line

> `prompt = "{uah}{cwd}" .. version_control .. get_lamb_color() .. cr .. "{env}{lamb} \x1b[0m"`

Answer (score 0):

Building on Eng_Farghly's advice (which works btw), you can get rid of the line break by removing **`\n`** from this line:

> `cr = "\n"`

this is in that same file, `\vendor\clink.lua`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1162394)

Comment: Well excuse me for trying to be helpful. It's no wonder why people hate posting in places like this.

Comment: This is an automated answer. I just told the system which answer to use. This is necessary because there are many people who write their first answer without reading the guide how to answer. Most of them just don’t know that they should read it, so this is the best way to tell them.